# Appfog - Spring application - Disk usage

Tags: java, mysql, spring, appfog

I have a Spring application running on **Appfog**.
App is connected to a Mysql DB and doesn't use disk storage (it only perform select or insert queries).
I noticed that the disk usage **increased** constantly in time (My database is very small, it can't be over 300MB).
This is a screenshot:
[image]
Why disk usage doesn't remain fixed?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We experienced similar behaviour with one of our apps. In our case we were using Hibernate with C3P0 resource pooling backed by EHCache as the storage backend provider. The default EHCache configuration has disk cache enabled which caches queries and loaded entities to the default Java temp dir. In cloud environments like Appfrog often the temp dir sits inside your user directory and thus accounts for your storage quota.

Obviously this cache can grow larger in size than the original database since the query cache may hold many different query results which can lead to data duplication in the disk cache.